# How does one develop a Shopify App in a local Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I've been having some trouble trying to set up a Shopify app so that I can develop it in my local Rails environment.

I've followed the documentation [HERE](http://shopify.github.io/shopify_app/) but when I install the app into my shopify dev store I get an error stating `localhost sent an invalid response.`

My local rails server log shows:

```
ERROR bad URI '::�+�/�,�0̨̩�\x14�\x13�\x13�\x14\x00�\x00�\x00/\x005\x00'.
ERROR bad Request-Line '\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03d��������\x1F�ŭ����=G�+q\r[��� N�\x00\x00 jj�+�/�,�0̨̩�\x14�\x13�\x13�\x14\x00�\x00�\x00/\x005\x00'.
```

After digging through other shopify docs I found this:

[image]

This says to tunnel with ngrok to avoid problems which makes sense, except that the shopify_app documentation states to specify `http://localhost:3000` as the application URL and `http://localhost:3000/auth/shopify/callback` as the Redirection URL.

Can anyone tell me how to set my Shopify app so I can develop it locally? Or is this something I will have to develop live on heroku?

Answer (score 2):

Ngrok is simply a tunnel to localhost, so you can set your application URL to `https://subdomain.ngrok.io` and redirection URL as `https://subdomain.ngrok.io/auth/shopify/callback`. You can configure ngrok to tunnel on port 3000 by specifying the port number when initializing ngrok: `./ngrok http 3000`.

Comment: I understand that. But having to go in and change the app settings every time I want to work on it is a bit of a hassle since the address changes every time I fire up ngrok. There has to be a better way.

Comment: @GavinTerrill I did not know that. It should be noted for future reference that only paid plans may bind custom subdomains. I'll have to find another solution as it isn't worth it for me to pay a $60 annual subscription when I'm only going to use it to work on this one app.

Comment: I found another tunnel service, [burrow.io](https://burrow.io) that allows customers to pay monthly. I was finally able to get the app installed.